# Move up view when textView show keyboard not working

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, textview, uitextfield

i have an one textView and textfield in storyboard. i want to move up scroll view when textfield or textView show keyboard. every thing work fine for UITextField but for textView thats not working. there is my code for moving up view:

```
  func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let endFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
      var keyboardHeight = view.bounds.height - endFrame.origin.y
      if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        if keyboardHeight > 0 {
          keyboardHeight = keyboardHeight - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
          var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
              contentInset.bottom = keyboardHeight
              viewBottom.constant = keyboardHeight
              self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
        }
      }
      else {
            let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.size
            var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
            contentInset.bottom = (keyboardSize.height)
            self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
      }
      view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

  }

  func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
    contentInset.bottom = 0
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset

  }
```

what is difference between textfield and textView for showing keyboard? 
when i tap textview that's method called and scroll view content inset same as when tap on textfield but view don't move up.
how can solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: did u manage to figure it out?

Comment: @Do2 i can't managed it. now i'm using IQKeyboardManagerSwift pod.

Comment: check my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class matchViewController: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate {
var activeTextview: UITextView?
@IBOutlet weak var yourTextview: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourTextview.delegate=self
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: self.view.window)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: self.view.window)

}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification) {

    var info: [AnyHashable : Any] = sender.userInfo!
    let kbSize: CGSize = ((info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size)
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    var aRect: CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height

    if let activeTextview=activeTextview{
        self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible((activeTextview.frame), animated: true)

    }

}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
    view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ sender: Notification) {
    let userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any] = sender.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size
    self.scrollView.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height


}


override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: self.view.window)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: self.view.window)
}



  func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    activeTextview=textView

}
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView){
    activeTextview=nil
}
}
```

Comment: with your code after hiding keyboard my view Drawn to the bottom. i change  self.scrollView.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height to   self.scrollView.frame.origin.y = 0, and this work fine. thanks for reply